# Convert POCO object to Proxy object in EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, proxy, poco

I have a MVC3 Project and I have run into a problem.  I have a Create controller which takes as a parameter one of my POCO objects.  I add this object to the database like this:

```
  entity = dbSet.Add(entity);
```

After this method returns, I would like to use the lazy loading features of the object.  Unfortunately the object is not a Proxy object generated by the EntityFramework...Is there a way to somehow solve this?

Thank You,
AFrieze

Comment: Are you using POCO proxies when working with you Create controller?  As far as I know, you cannot do a mix of POCO and POCO Proxies because one of the requirements of the Entity Framework and POCO proxies is to set ObjectContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled to true, which enables proxies across the whole ObjectContext.  Here is a good link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx.

Comment: The MVC3 project is completely unaware of the entity framework, it references the Models project(POCO objects) and the BAL(Repository access).  Lazy loading works great at all levels of the project as long as I'm working with an object I queried from the database.  The basic issue is that I can create an object in the MVC3 project and pass it to my BAL which saves it and attaches it to the context appropriately...but I'm left with a reference to a POCO object and not a proxy object that can make use of lazy loading.

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha.  If you send info to the BAL and modify the BAL to use ObjectContext.CreateObject(...), then return the resulting object, that object should be POCO proxy as long as all the proxy rules are met.  The issue is you are using entity = dbSet.Add(entity) which does not create a POCO proxy object.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  My current solution is similiar, my repository takes a POCO object, calls dbset.Generate(), then maps all the fields in my POCO object to the new PROXY object and switch the reference.  This seem very inelegant.  Is there no way to take an Attached POCO object and get the PROXY representation of it?

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, not auto-magically.  You'll have to translate as you are doing.

Comment: NOooooo.  Thanks for the info, I'm still hoping to find a way to fix this inelegance...others must have encountered this as I know the repository pattern is popular with the Entity Framework.

Comment: You can't "convert". You must create a new object and copy the properties. EF can help with copying, using `CurrentValues.SetValues` (at least for scalar and complex properties) as shown here in the question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7969451/270591. Or use explicite loading instead of lazy loading, as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entity must be already proxied when you pass it to `Add` method. `Add` method will not return another instance of the class and you cannot change the type of the existing instance to the proxy type.

Your options are:

- Not using entity as input in controller - use some view model and populate new entity created by `dbSet.Create` - this will create empty proxied detached entity.
- Instead of adding the entity received in controller create a new one by `dbSet.Create` and copy data from received one to created one
- Don't use default model binder. Create custom model binder (that is the code responsible for extracting data from HTTP request and populating parameters passed to controller) which will use `dbSet.Create` instead of default entity constructor.